# How do I write a regular expression to match a word if it is at the beginning of a line or if there is a space in front of it?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I’m using Ruby 2.3.  How do I write a regular expression that will find a word with either a space in front of it or the beginning of the string in front of it?  I have this string …

```
2.3.0 :001 > string = "time abcd”
 => "time abcd"
```

and I can write

```
2.3.0 :003 > string.index(/^time/)
 => 0
```

but I’m looking to come up with a more generic regular expression that will match my word if it is at the beginning of a line or if there is a single space in front of it.

Comment: By "or if there is a single space in front of it" can the space be anywhere is the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
re = /
  (?<=        # just before this, match
     ^        # the start of the string
     |        # or
     \s       # a single whitespace
   )          # and then
   time       # the literal string "time"
/x

# or equivalently: re = /(?<=^|\s)time/

"time abcd".index(re)
# => 0
```